# prove the existence of a zero for the equation $az^2-z+1=0$ in a domain $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the equation $az^2-z+1=0$. Prove the existence of a zero $\overline{z}$ in $D = \{z \mid \mid z-1\mid \leq 1\}$ for every $a \in \mathbb{C}$.

I tried to solve it using Rouche Theorem, but I can't prove it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you tell us what $D$ is? And is $a$ a real number or a non-real, complex number?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it now!

Comment: Consider $f(z)=1-z$ and $g(z)=az^2$ and apply the theorem.

Comment: But the estimate $\mid az^2 \mid \leq \mid1-z \mid$ does not hold in the boundary of $D$, so i don't understand your point. Can you explain it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with elementary calculations, and without using Rouché's theorem.

To simplify the notation we substitute $w = z-1$, so that the task is to find a solution $w$  of the equation
$$
\tag{*}
a(w+1)^2 - (w+1) + 1 = aw^2 + (2a-1)w + a  = 0 \, .
$$
satisfying $|w|  \le 1$.

If $a=0$ then $w=0$ is such a solution. For $a \ne 0$, $(*)$ is equivalent to
$$
 w^2 - \frac{2a-1}{a}w + 1 = 0 \,  .
$$
This  quadratic equation has two complex  solutions $w_1, w_2$ (which may coincide or not). But Vieta's formulas tell us that $w_1 w_2 = 1$, and therefore one of the solutions must satisfy $|w_j| \le 1$.